# Connecting to external SSL TCP socket what does it really mean?

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp

Im writing a small app that is connecting to a socket on a server I dont know the implementation details of. In the documentation of the socket it says

> All communication on the socket is using SSL

When I try to figure out what is required by the client to be able to communicate over SSL I get very confused because SSL requires details about key stores and certificates.

All I have access to is the host adress and the socket port and this should be enogh according to the server owners.

My question is how can a socket use SSL but there is no requirements of the client to provide certificates etc (which the SSL standard seems to require)?

How do I know what is required to setup on the client to connect to a SSL socket?

The language im using is Java/Scala and Im required to provide `SSLContext`
which will be used to create a `SSLEngine`.

This is the naive way I tried wich do not work.

```
val sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault()
```

How would a minimal example look for configuring SSLContext and generating a SSLEngine for the use case im looking at?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  On what platform(s)? There are SSL libraries available for most languages and platforms, that handle these kind of details for you. There is no requirement in the SSL standard that says a *client* must have a certificate, though it is certainly an option if the *server* needs to validate a client's identity. Most public servers do not require *client* certificates, but they have their own certificates so *clients* can validate the server's identity.

Comment: That is handled by SSL libraries during SSL handshakes, though.  You usually don't need to be directly involve in that process, unless you need to implement your own custom validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

> All communication on the socket is using SSL

If this is all what is known about the server than it is probably using a certificate from a well established CA issued to the hostname of the server. In this case you will find lots of examples in several programming languages on how to create a SSL client with such a server.

If this assumption is not correct and the examples don't work you need more details about the server, i.e. about the certificates used, the ciphers used, TLS protocol spoken etc. And then you can adapt your program to these requirements.

To expand the answer after you've provided details about the programming language you are using: Searching for [scala ssl client example](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+ssl+client+example) gives you lot of information which help you start.

Comment: Could you please expand your answere, im not sure what you are saying. Could you also sugest what I should google to get examples of Java/Scala clients that uses such implementation.

Comment: In Java, look at the [`SSLSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) and [`SSLSocketFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) classes.